# HMS Awareness Kit-Error code 10011 is returned after the SDK is integrated

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I integrated the HMS Core Awareness SDK and then called the getWeatherByDevice API to query weather data, but an error occurred: com.huawei.hms.kit.awareness.b.HHG: Error Code: 10005 Desc: barrier or capture frequency limit. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is caused by too frequent API calls. Currently, there are two restrictions on calling the APIs of HUAWEI Awareness Kit:

1. The number of API calls within 1 hour cannot exceed 1000.
2. The number of API calls within 5 seconds cannot exceed 20.

The reasons for such restrictions are as follows:

1. Frequent API calls in a short period of time are not normal service requirements.
2. Frequent API calls increase the workload of HMS Core and even cause a failure to provide services for other developers.

The restrictions are only a temporary workaround, and will be eliminated after service optimization.