# Why do I get error code 10009 when running HMS Awareness code?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

When I am running HMS Bahavior Awareness getting the given error

**com.huawei.hms.kit.awareness.b.HHG:Error Code:10009 Desc**

Application is running in non HMS device with the help of HMS Core App.

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62034152/hms-awareness-kit-error-code-10011-is-returned-after-the-sdk-is-integrated

Answer (score 0):

you can check this link [Result Codes](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-References/error_code) to understand the meanings of error codes

10009 - tooManyTask - The number of ongoing data export tasks of an app exceeds the upper limit (3).