# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick In HMS Scan Kit

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

I'm trying to implement the Scan kit getting below error.

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.huawei.hmsscankitexample, PID: 27532
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7213)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7187)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:828)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27675)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8285)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7213) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7187) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:828) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27675) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8285) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.java:1544)
        at com.huawei.hmsscankitexample.activity.ProfileActivity.downloadQrCode(ProfileActivity.java:218)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7213) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7187) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:828) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27675) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8285) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055) 
2020-07-16 22:22:06.951 27532-27532/com.huawei.hmsscankitexample I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27532 SIG: 9
```

Comment: add `ProfileActivity.java`

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're getting a Null Pointer exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at 
android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.java:1544) at 
com.huawei.hmsscankitexample.activity.ProfileActivity.downloadQrCode(ProfileActivity.java:218)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the documentation on the Huawei Developer website for more information on result codes. Here is the [link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-References/error_code).

Result Code 10009  “The number of ongoing data export tasks of an app exceeds the upper limit (3).”

The answer provided in the link below explains further why this error occurs.
[HMS Awareness Kit-Error code 10011 is returned after the SDK is integrated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62034152/hms-awareness-kit-error-code-10011-is-returned-after-the-sdk-is-integrated)

```
This error is caused by too frequent API calls. Currently, there are two restrictions on calling the APIs of HUAWEI Awareness Kit:
 
1.  The number of API calls within 1 hour cannot exceed 1000.
2.  The number of API calls within 5 seconds cannot exceed 20.
 
The reasons for such restrictions are as follows:
 
1.  Frequent API calls in a short period of time are not normal service requirements.
2.  Frequent API calls increase the workload of HMS Core and even cause a failure to provide services for other developers.
 
The restrictions are only a temporary workaround, and will be eliminated after service optimization.
```